# Multi line variable not getting created

Tags: php

What is the problem with this following code?

```
class EMAIL_BODY{
   public $REGISTRATION = <<<EOF
        <html>
                <head>
                </head>
                <body style='font-family: helvetica;'>
                        Welcome <b>#{FIRST}</b>, <br/> You have successfully created your account.
                        However, there is one more step that you need to take to verify your account.
                        Please click the below given link to activate your account.
                        Unless you do that your account won\'t get activated. <br/>

                        <a> #{LINK} </a>

                </body>
        </html>

    EOF;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must put the closing delimiter of your [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) `EOF;` right at the start of the line:

> It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except ***possibly*** a semicolon (`;`). That means especially that the identifier ***may not be indented***, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon.

So:

```
class EMAIL_BODY{
   public $REGISTRATION = <<<EOF
        …
EOF;
}
```

Comment: You mean no spaces on the ending line? I tried that but still not working.

Comment: I think heredoc marker doesn't work at instance variable level. It howvever works fine when the same variable is in some function and i return that variable.